# compute $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Z)$ (p-adic integers)

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

How can I compute $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Z)$ or $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q)$? (By $\mathbb Z_p$ I mean p-adic integers.)

Comment: Posted as a comment because it only solves the easier half of the question: Let $\varphi:\mathbb Z_p\to\mathbb Z$ be a group homomorphism. Pick $n>1$ such that $p\nmid n$. Also let $a\in\mathbb Z_p$. Then $\varphi(a)=n^m\varphi(a/n^m)$ so $\varphi(a/n^m)=\varphi(a)/n^m\in\mathbb Z$ for all $m\ge 1$, so $\varphi(a)=0$.

Comment: My intuition says $\mathbb{Z}_p$ should be a free module over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ (i.e. rational numbers with denominator relatively prime to $p$) of uncountable rank.  If this is true, then you should be able to arbitrarily assign a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-basis to elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ and extend by linearily, and this space would therefore be pretty unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this a fully satisfactory answer, but I want to share the following construction proving, at least when assuming a suitable set theory, the existence of very many homomorphisms of additive groups from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to $\Bbb{Q}$, and also to provide a certain kind of census of them.

Consider the field of $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb{Q}_p$. It is an extension of the field $\Bbb{Q}$, so it is a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. If we accept the Axiom of Choice this implies that there exists a $\Bbb{Q}$-basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\Bbb{Q}_p$. Furthermore, as $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is uncountable, so is $\mathcal{B}$.
We thus have a large supply of $\Bbb{Q}$-linear mappings $f:\Bbb{Q}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$. Namely, any function $\tilde{f}:\mathcal{B}\to\Bbb{Q}$ gives rise to a unique linear transformation $f$ in the usual way.

Composing any such $f$ with the inclusion mapping $i:\Bbb{Z}_p\to\Bbb{Q}_p$ gives a homomorphism $F:=f\circ i:\Bbb{Z}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$.

A few remarks are due:

- Any homomorphism $f$ of additive groups from $\Bbb{Q}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$ is actually a linear transformation. If $q=m/n\in\Bbb{Q}$ and $z\in\Bbb{Q}_p$ are arbitrary then $y:=f(qz)$ must satisfy the equation $$ny=nf(qz)=f(nqz)=f(mz)=mf(z).$$ This equation has a unique solution $y=qf(z)$ in $\Bbb{Q}$ proving linearity.
- Every element $z\in\mathcal{B}$ is of the form $z=x/p^{n}$ for some $x\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}$. So without loss of generality we can assume that $\mathcal{B}\subset\Bbb{Z}_p$. Consequently different choices of $f$ give rise to different homomorphisms $F$.
- Because $\Bbb{Q}$ is divisible, it is [an injective object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_object) in the category of abelian groups. Therefore any homomorphism $F:\Bbb{Z}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$ can be lifted to a corresponding homomorphism $f:\Bbb{Q}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$ such that $F=f\circ i$. In other words, we have accounted for all the homomorphisms of addtive groups $\in Hom(\Bbb{Z}_p,\Bbb{Q}).$

> The homomorphisms of additive groups $\Bbb{Z}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$ are the restrictions of $\Bbb{Q}$-linear transformations $\Bbb{Q}_p\to\Bbb{Q}$. Distinct transformations have distinct restrictions, so in this sense
>   $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_p, \mathbb Q)$ is the dual space $\widehat{\Bbb{Q}_p}.$

Comment: The argument in the comment of RJM shows that there are no non-trivial homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to $\Bbb{Z}$. But, I'm wondering about the idea in Nate's comment! Torsion-free does not imply free (over a PID) when the modules are not finitely generated, so that question may be quite difficult.